# How does the jvm handle the java thread throws exception

Tags: exception, jvm, gdb

```java
public class Hello
{
    static class T {
        static {
            int i = 1 / 0;
        }

        static void t() {
            System.out.println("hello world;");
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world;");

        T.t();
    }
}
```

In the above code, when executing the main method, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError will be thrown.

I used GDB to debug this piece of code, and the JVM threw an exception when executing the  method of Hello$T.

I used gdb to add a dot at [this location](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/oops/instanceKlass.cpp#L1205), then add watch point

```bash
(gdb) print jt
$1 = (JavaThread *) 0xfffff0027bf0

(gdb) watch $1->_pending_exception
Hardware watchpoint 3: $1->_pending_exception

(gdb) c
Continuing.

Thread 2 "java" hit Hardware watchpoint 3: $1->_pending_exception

Old value = (oop) 0x0
New value = (oop) 0x75a5d2d20
0x0000ffffe85372d0 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000ffffe85372d0 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000fffff69a4ef8 in os::os_exception_wrapper (f=0xfffff53f3a00, value=0xfffff53f39e8, method=..., args=0xfffff0027d70, thread=0xfffff003eb80)
    at /home/parallels/openjdk/src/hotspot/os/linux/os_linux.cpp:4810
#2  0x0000fffff69a4ef8 in os::os_exception_wrapper (f=0xfffff53f3a08, value=0xfffff53f3820, method=..., args=0xfffff0027d70, thread=0xffffe854af80)
    at /home/parallels/openjdk/src/hotspot/os/linux/os_linux.cpp:4810
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

The above is the output of gdb. **What confuses me is whether the top stack information is a Java stack. If it is a Java stack, can it show that `_pending_exception` is directly assigned by the Java thread? If so, where should I find this code?**